# What method(s) does the ts Function interface declare

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I recently started learning typescript & angular and then, I came across a short code like this `interface transform extends Function{ (param:string):string; }`

So I'm wondering, what kind of methods or return types the `transform` interface inherited from the `Function` interface? Again if I decide to have a method that returns `transform` like so: `coordinate ():transform { }`, what are the types expected of coordinate to return aside `string`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`extends Function` adds `Function` methods like `call` `apply` etc... and also the `Function` behavior, but it's redundant as you have a function definition inside the interface:

```
interface ExtendedFunction extends Function { }

declare const extendedFunction: ExtendedFunction;

extendedFunction.apply // Works
extendedFunction('bla', 1, true); // Works

interface Transform {
  (param: string): string;
}

declare const transform: Transform;

transform.apply // Works
transform('bla', 1, true) // Fails
transform('bla') // Works
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIA9IgCYWwMQFcQExgB7EZCTCHAZ2SJLMuQG9kBfAWACh%20uBABs4UFAkr0w1WjjzNSFEAC40c3AWJLKAbn78aWTYtYgAdHAAOV4QE9kAekfIA6uSgBreoY0LtZgAUAOQARqLBADTIAIzRYFCEEACUuk4u7l4%20AnygkLCIKAAqUHAg9DAeALYc-MjIgVZicFVq0lCgAObJbQld%20ny8OUKi4siS5TIJZRXVaiUzlVBVA-zT5UtVljb26W4e3mulG9Uh4XBRsfGJKXv4cMDC2euzy2cRyXuZ3kA)